# File "stringsource", in spacy.pipeline.pipe.Pipe.__setstate_cython__ TypeError: Expected tuple, got dict

Tags: python, nlp, pickle, spacy

I was working in google colab on pickling and unpickling a spacy model and I managed to do that using those two lines
import pickle

```
with open('nlp_pickle.pkl','wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(nlp,f)
with open('/content/nlp_pickle.pkl','rb') as g:
  nlp1=pickle.load(g)
```

then i downloaded the model and tried to use it in an application
import pickle

```
with open(r'C:\Desktop\test ner\nlp_pickle.pkl','rb') as g:
  nlp=pickle.load(g)
```

and i got this error

```
    nlp=pickle.load(g)
  File "stringsource", line 17, in spacy.pipeline.pipe.Pipe.__setstate_cython__
TypeError: Expected tuple, got dict
```

when i google it i found literally nothing so can anyone help me to fix it

Comment: Are you sure you have the same spaCy version on colab and your local machine?

Comment: @polm23 no it's not the same i'm going to change the version and try again

Comment: i changed the virsion and i got another error

Comment: File "vocab.pyx", line 607, in spacy.vocab.unpickle_vocab
  File "C:\Users\KS527EU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\srsly\_pickle_api.py", line 23, in pickle_loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(data)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

Comment: Please edit your question when you have new information instead of adding comments. Also please add the different version of spacy involved.